# Load classes of java project

Tags: java, eclipse

I am loading all the source classes of a selected project using below code,

```
IPackageFragment[] packages = javaProject.getPackageFragments();
for (IPackageFragment mypackage : packages) {      
if (mypackage.getKind() == IPackageFragmentRoot.K_SOURCE) {
    for (ICompilationUnit unit : mypackage.getCompilationUnits()) {
        // code here
    }    
}
```

However, consider a project having structure below

ProjectName -> src -> main -> org -> odlabs -> wiquery -> core -> JQueryAjaxOption.java

```
               -> test -> org -> odlabs -> wiquery -> core -> JQueryAjaxOptionTestCase.java
```

Now, the above two classes have same package but located in different folder.

I have two question here

1. Is it possible that i can exclude test folder in my code above? I check class "IPackageFragmentRoot" but could not find anything...
2. Can project conceptually contain two different folders (apart from "test" folder) having classes with same package name? (technically yes it is possible).

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can exclude the test folder. If you use maven, for example, you can indicate which folder contains your test classes: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html
2. You can have a project with many source folders. Just as you mentioned, "main" and "test". But test classes are not included in the final jar. If both classes were in the "main" folder then it would be a source of confusion and you should consider renaming one of them.

Comment: I think I could not explain my question clearly. I am actually creating eclipse plugin using which user select project and the plugin will load classes information. Now, this is an example project which I am trying to load. I hope you understand my query.